# SQL: Slicing DateRange data by year (Tricky)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this very tricky problem and Im trying to figure it out for a while now,

I have this query result set

```
    SELECT * FROM Orders

    OrderID | OrderAmount | OrderDate | Expiry Date
    1        $100          2008-01-01    2009-12-31
    2        $200          2009-01-01    2010-12-31
    3        $300          2010-01-01    2011-12-31
    4        $3            2010-01-01    2010-06-31
    5        $400          2007-01-01    2009-05-31
```

Now, how can i break down each order by OrderDate - ExpiryDate daterange per YEAR

I want the result something like this in my RDLC report

```
    ORDERS CONSUMED PER YEAR    

    OrderID  |  YEAR     |    Consumed Amount
     1         2008           $50
     1         2009           $50
     2         2009           $100
     2         2010           $100
     3         2010           $150
     3         2011           $150  
     4         2010           $3
     5         2007           $160
     5         2008           $160
     5         2009           $80   <---- another tricky part
```

The computation is base on the term, eq. (2 year term of $300 means $150 per year)

How can i do this in MS-SQL Query?

** I know the title seems incorrect ^^, i just cant find the right title

Edited: added more samples and explanation

Comment: Why is the amount of orderId 2 only for 2009 and not split?

Comment: Does each year always get the same, "CREDIT", say for example Order Date = 1-July-2010 and ExpiryDate = 31-Dec-2011, and order amount is $150. Does each year get $75, and equal amount? Or does 2010 get $50, and 2011 get $100, proportional to how much of each year is covered?

Comment: its more on the latter, its proportional base on the term (range). please see my additional explanation above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is SQL Server 2005 or later, you can use a common table expression to recursively build a table of months and use that to calculate the order amount consumed per year.

A few notes:

1. This solution assumes that the time periods are based on whole months.  The approach is to determine the amount of the order consumed per month, then multiply that by the number of months in the year.  You could modify this to use an amount consumed per day if needed.
2. In the final `select`, I cast from `money` to a `decimal` with higher precision to try and avoid rounding problems.  You may have to adjust this to fit your needs, but I'm not sure that you will be able to avoid rounding problems entirely.
3. The results for OrderID 5 don't match your sample results.  This is because the example has 5 months in 2009, not 6.

---

```
create table #Orders
(
    OrderID int,
    OrderAmount money,
    OrderDate datetime,
    ExpiryDate datetime
)

insert into #Orders values(1, 100, '2008-01-01', '2009-12-31'),
                          (2, 200, '2009-01-01', '2010-12-31'),
                          (3, 300, '2010-01-01', '2011-12-31'),
                          (4, 3,   '2010-01-01', '2010-06-30'),
                          (5, 400, '2007-01-01', '2009-05-31')

;with cte_months
as
(
    select OrderID, OrderDate, year(OrderDate) OrderYear
    from #Orders
    union all
    select m.OrderID, dateadd(month, 1, m.OrderDate), year(dateadd(month, 1, m.OrderDate)) 
    from cte_months m
        inner join #Orders o on m.OrderID = o.OrderID
    where dateadd(month, 1, m.OrderDate) <= o.ExpiryDate
)
select m.OrderId, m.OrderYear, cast(sum(o.MonthlyAmount) as money) as ConsumedAmount
from
(
    select OrderID, cast(OrderAmount as decimal(12,6)) / (datediff(month, orderdate, ExpiryDate) + 1) as MonthlyAmount
    from #Orders
) o inner join cte_months m on o.OrderID = m.OrderID
group by m.OrderID, m.OrderYear

drop table #Orders
```

And the results:

```
OrderId     OrderYear   ConsumedAmount
----------- ----------- ---------------------
1           2008        50.00
1           2009        50.00
2           2009        100.00
2           2010        100.00
3           2010        150.00
3           2011        150.00
4           2010        3.00
5           2007        165.5172
5           2008        165.5172
5           2009        68.9655
```

Comment: precisely what i need, +1 and v/

Answer (score 1):

From your limited dataset, where every order spawns exactly two years, you could do this:

```
SELECT orderId, Year(OrderDate) AS Year, orderamount/2 AS amount FROM orders
UNION
SELECT orderId, Year(Expiry Date) AS Year, orderamount/2 AS amount
```

Assuming you have data with spawning *at most* two years (but maybe only one):

```
SELECT orderId, year, sum(amount)
FROM (
  SELECT orderId, Year(OrderDate) year, orderamount/2 amount FROM orders
  UNION
  SELECT orderId, Year(Expiry Date) year, orderamount/2 amount FROM orders
) GROUP By orderId, year
```

If you want to spawn any number of years, it does indeed get tricky. The following is some recursive SQL that should work for [DB2](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/ad/samples/clp/s-flt-db2.htm)/[MSSQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx):

```
WITH expanded_orders (orderid, year)
AS 
(
  SELECT orderid, year(OrderDate) FROM orders
  UNION ALL
  SELECT orderid, year + 1 FROM expanded_orders
  WHERE year + 1 <= (SELECT year(expiry date) FROM orders WHERE orders.orderid = exanded_orders.orderid)
)

SELECT exp.orderid, exp.year, 
  orders.amount / (SELECT count(*) FROM expanded_orders this WHERE this.orderid = exp.orderid)
FROM expanded_orders exp, orders
WHERE exp.orderid = orders.orderid
```

I didn't test the query, so it might have a syntax error, but the general approach should be sound.

UPDATE: I just saw your added examples. This approach will not work for years that are not fully used, in that case, the second select would have to be adapted to not evenly divide on the fringes. But I think that should be solvable using 'traditional' sql.

Comment: its not always exactly 2 years, the order date -expir ate could vary from 1 month range to 10 years, i just use it as example for easy slicing ^^

Comment: You should vary your examples a bit more then so it's clear :) And you should also indicate what database you are using so people can give you specific SQL, as often, when such tricky stuff is needed, the common standard SQL doesn't cut it.

Comment: im going to try this approach ^^

Answer (score 1):

As [inflagranti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/369310/inflagranti) pointed out my first solution sufferred problems if there were holes in the years covered by the Orders table. I was trying to dynamically create the set of the years needed.

A more straight forward solution would be to use a [numbers or tally table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/) to supply the years. My tally table is called Number, and has a single column N of type int, with the number 0 through 1,000,000 inclusive. Use the tally table to provide the years to join against to get the multiple rows for an Order that spans years. For ConsumedAmount I'm calculating the OrderAmount * (days in the year for the order / days of the order.) If you want something diffent, like months, or weeks, or anything fiscally, you will need to modify.

Note I'm also using SQL Server 2008 features, specifically the `date` data type, which is new in 2008. The method of getting YearNumber, YearStartDate and YearEndDate from the number tally table would be different prior to 2008.

Note also the numbers are slightly off from you example because of the extra day in leap years.

```
; With Y as (select N as YearNumber
        , dateadd(year, N-1, cast('0001-01-01' as date)) as YearStartDate
        , dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(year, N, cast('0001-01-01' as date))) 
             as YearEndDate
    from Number)
select O.OrderId
    , Y.YearNumber
    -- Next column is the OrderAmount * the ratio of 
    -- number of days in this year for this order
    -- divided by the number of days of the order.
    , OrderAmount * -- multiply the Order amount by the ratio of
        ((case when year(OrderDate) = year(Expirydate)
                then datediff(day, OrderDate, ExpiryDate) 
            when YearNumber = year(OrderDate)
                then datediff(day, OrderDate, YearEndDate)
            when YearNumber = year(ExpiryDate)
                then datediff(day, YearStartDate, ExpiryDate)
            else datediff(day, YearStartDate, YearEndDate) end + 1)
        / cast(datediff(day, OrderDate, ExpiryDate) + 1 as float))
from Orders O
inner join Y on Y.YearNumber between year(OrderDate) and year(ExpiryDate)
order by O.OrderId, YearNumber
```

Test data:

```
create table Orders (OrderId int not null constraint Orders_PK primary key
    , OrderAmount money
    , OrderDate date
    , ExpiryDate date)
go

insert into Orders
values (1, 100, '2008-01-01', '2009-12-31')
, (2, 200, '2009-01-01', '2010-12-31')
, (3, 300, '2010-01-01', '2011-12-31')
, (4, 3, '2010-01-01', '2010-06-30')
, (5, 400, '2007-01-01', '2009-05-31')
, (100, 1000, '2010-01-01', '2019-12-31')
```

Query Results:

```
OrderId     YearNumber  
----------- ----------- ----------------------
1           2008        50.0683994528044
1           2009        49.9316005471956
2           2009        100
2           2010        100
3           2010        150
3           2011        150
4           2010        3
5           2007        165.532879818594
5           2008        165.986394557823
5           2009        68.4807256235828
100         2010        99.9452354874042
100         2011        99.9452354874042
100         2012        100.219058050383
100         2013        99.9452354874042
100         2014        99.9452354874042
100         2015        99.9452354874042
100         2016        100.219058050383
100         2017        99.9452354874042
100         2018        99.9452354874042
100         2019        99.9452354874042
```

Comment: Yes and no. It will work if the multi year range of a record is filled in by other records, but it can fail. Will correct later. Right side should be a tally table.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to approach this would be to use this - this works for up to 2047 years in the future, and if more is needed some kind of numbers table would be useful, although I don't think this is as efficient as adrift's solution!

```
create table #Orders      (OrderID int,     OrderAmount money,     OrderDate datetime,     ExpiryDate datetime   )
insert into #Orders 
SELECT 1 as orderid, 100 as orderamount, '2008-01-01' as orderdate, '2009-12-31' as expirydate UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 200, '2009-01-01', '2010-12-31' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 300, '2010-01-01', '2011-12-31' UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 3,   '2010-01-01', '2010-06-30' UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 400, '2007-01-01', '2009-05-31' 

SELECT 
orderid 
,orderamount as total_order_amount
,YEAR(orderdate) + number as orderyear
,CASE WHEN 
DATEDIFF(MM,orderdate,expirydate) - (12 * (YEAR(orderdate) - YEAR(orderdate) + number)) 
> 12 THEN 12 * CAST(orderamount / DATEDIFF(MM,orderdate,expirydate)  AS DECIMAL(18,5)) 
ELSE 
(DATEDIFF(MM,orderdate,expirydate) % 12 * 
CAST(orderamount / DATEDIFF(MM,orderdate,expirydate)  AS DECIMAL(18,5))) END as amount
,CAST(orderamount / DATEDIFF(MM,orderdate,expirydate)  AS DECIMAL(18,5)) as monthly_value
from #orders
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
select number from spt_values
where type = 'p'
) numbers on numbers.number <= DATEDIFF(YY,orderdate,expirydate)
```

Comment: presicely what i need, +1 and a v/ ^^